# Can't unlock my Acer B3-A30 tablet's bootloader

Tags: fastboot, boot-loop, boot, bootloader, bootloader-lock

So I have an Acer Acer B3-A30 tablet, which is stuck on the Acer logo.
I'm trying to unlock it's bootloader (with fastboot mode), so I can reflash it (with a stock rom), but it just shows an error saying "Failed to unlock bootloader."
I've checked both of the commands `fastboot oem unlock` and `fastboot flashing unlock`, but they just don't want to work. I haven't installed root or any system modifications, this is my first time ever doing so.
It would be even better, if someone told me how to fix it without bootloader unlocking and these other stuff.

Comment: fastboot flashing get_unlock_ability = 1?

Comment: @alecxs this is what i got : fastboot: usage: unknown 'flashing' command get_unlock_ability

Comment: https://github.com/bkerler/mtkclient#unlock-bootloader

Comment: @alecxs
"you need to enable usb-debugging via Settings/About phone/Version, Tap 7x on build number
Go to Settings/Additional settings/Developer options, enable "OEM unlock" and "USB Debugging"
"
I can't boot the device to enable those.

Comment: @alecxs It keeps displaying "Handshake failed, retrying..."

Comment: @alecxs the only thing i need is to somehow enable oem unlock without dev settings and i can do the rest by my self

Comment: @alecxs I figured out how to use it, but it's stuck at "DALegacy - Reconnecting to preloader"

Comment: @alecxs shows this : "Done |--------------------------------------------------| 0.0% Read (Sector 0x0 of 0x200) 0.00 MB/sDA_handler
DA_handler - [LIB]: ←[31mUnknown seccfg partition header. Aborting unlock.←[0m"

Comment: so it connected, but this tool won't unlock. your goal is flashing stock ROM, can be done from SP Flash Tool or mtkclient (on locked bootloader)

Comment: @alecxs When selecting the scatter.txt file, it displays an error.

Comment: make sure the scatter file is for your device. delete the checksum from scatter file

Comment: @alexcs I found the original rom, but it still doesn't want to flash it.

Comment: flash from mtkclient

Comment: @alexcs Preloader - [LIB]: ←[31mError on DA_Send cmd←[0m

Comment: https://github.com/bkerler/mtkclient/issues/140

Comment: @alexcs what to do with that?